# How to bind MapIcon on Bing Map in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I use the Bing Map on my Windows Phone 8.1 app. Precisally, in XAML file, I wrote

```
<Maps:MapControl x:Name="Map" Loaded="Map_Loaded">
    <Maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}">
        <Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="Images/arte_icon_label.png"
                       Height="25"
                       Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Geopoint}"
                       Maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint=".5,.5"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </Maps:MapItemsControl>
</Maps:MapControl>
```

I want to add many Images, but I don't know what is the code procedure to add theme.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to add multiple MapIcon with C# code? I get this code snippet from following [post](http://hintdesk.com/universal-app-bing-map-get-current-location-show-pins-and-search-near-by/).

```
private async Task SearchNearbyIncidents(Geopoint location)
{
    IList<Geopoint> geoPoints = await bingMapRestService.GetIncidents(MapUtil.GetBoundingBox(location.Position, 5), ConstantValues.BingMapKey);
    foreach (var geoPoint in geoPoints)
    {
        MapIcon mapIcon = new MapIcon
        {
            Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/TrafficYield.png")),
            Location = geoPoint,
            NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 0.5),
            Title = "Incidents"
        };
        mapControl.MapElements.Add(mapIcon);
    }
}
```

Comment: I try to use this code, but the MapIcon does not show with a zoom level less than 15D. 
Do you know how to use ItemSource (or something similar) property?